# Kibana dashboard not loading - {"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"not found"}

Tags: kubernetes, kibana, kubernetes-helm

I am installing kibana with helm like so

```
 values = [
    <<-EOT
    replicas: 3
    healthCheckPath: /admin/kibana/app/kibana
    kibanaConfig:
      kibana.yml: |
        server.basePath: "/admin/kibana"
        server.rewriteBasePath: true
    ingress:
      enabled: true
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
        kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
      path: /admin/kibana
```

I want kibana to be served at path `/admin/kibana`. eg. https://my-server.com/admin/kibana

I see the error `{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"not found"}`

In the logs

```
"res":{"statusCode":404,"responseTime":24,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET / 404 24ms - 9.0B"}
```

The pods are running fine which means health check is passing at `/admin/kibana`.

I have the `server.basePath` set as per documentation. What else is missing?

If I port-forward 5601 from my box,

```
kubectl port-forward svc/kibana 5601:5601
```

I can access kibana at `localhost:5601/admin/kibana`. But not on the domain.

The ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  labels:
    app: kibana
    heritage: Tiller
    release: kibana
  name: kibana-kibana
spec:
  rules:
  - host: xxxx.xxxx.app
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: kibana-kibana
          servicePort: 5601
        path: /admin/kibana
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - xxxx.xxxx.app
    secretName: wildcard-alchemy-tls
```

Comment: Could you provide some information about your env? Local or On-Prem? What K8s and Helm version are you using. Could you provide link to helm chart?

Comment: The cluster is on gcp: 1.12.10-gke.17. helm version is 2.14. I am using kibana 7.3.2

Comment: What do you see in Kong ingress pod logs?

Comment: Could you provide some logs from `kibana`? Could you provide your svc yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kong ingress by default was stripping path. Hence the issue.